# Query in Sequelize Relationships

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I need to get information from 3 tables I'm relating to, but I have no idea how to do this with sequelize, I didn't find anything in the documentation on how to do this

model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require ('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database/index');

class Products extends Model {
    static init(sequelize){
        super.init({
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            float: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
            price: DataTypes.DOUBLE
        }, {sequelize, tableName:'products'});
    }
    static associate(models){
        this.belongsTo(models.SubCategory, { foreignKey: 'subcategory_id', as:'subcategory'});
        this.belongsTo(models.Exteriors, { foreignKey: 'exterior_id', as:'exteriors'});
        this.belongsTo(models.Types, { foreignKey: 'type_id', as:'types'})
    }
}

module.exports =  Products;
```

funct:

```
async getAllProduct(req,res){
    try {
        const products = await Products.findAll({});
        if(result){return res.status(200).json({result})}
        else{return res.status(400).json({result: 'failed to get Products'})}
     } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for eager loading, which involves using include on your resolver to nest associations on one query.  Include's can also use where, order and other tools to filter results.

```
Products.findAll({
include: [
   {model: models.SubCategory, as: 'subcategory', include: [
     {model: models.Exteriors, as: 'exteriors', include: [/* etc */]
   ]}
  ]
  ]}.then(function(products) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(products))
```